QGIS graphical modeler: Buffer distance of dif. Layers by value out of Excel spreadsheet
I started a project, where I buffer layers (lines and polygons). In total there are 15 or 20 layers and i have to do some steps to use the layers. To make it easy and fast, i want to create a tool with the graphical modeler.
For the process it would be best, if the user first writes the size of the buffer into an Excel or CSV file, load it into QGIS and use the model for the process.
The layers have to be selected by the user, but the buffer size should come from the Excel sheet.
Is there a way to connect the buffer size to the Excel sheet or to a specific cell?
Down there, a pattern of the workflow


Can you add a screenshot of the excel file? Is it only one value, or a unique value for each layer?

Is it unique value for each layer.
Highway 200, main road 100, country 75, rail 150
